# Is there a lower-level alternative to RwLock?

Tags: rust

In my low-ish level library, I want the functionality of a `RwLock`, but instead of holding a `RwLockReadGuard` or `RwLockWriteGuard`, I want to manually tell the `RwLock`-like object when the read or write lock has been released.

Is there portable public interface in std for this, even if unsafe?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "low-ish level" but you could probably write yourself some structure with atomic counting. The question is, will the risk that comes with this be worth for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in std (although you can use `RwLock<()>`, but you still have to hold the guard around), but in `parking_lot` there is [`RawRwLock`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/struct.RawRwLock.html):

```rust
use parking_lot::lock_api::RawRwLock as _;
use parking_lot::RawRwLock;

let rwlock = RawRwLock::INIT;

// Write access
rwlock.lock_exclusive();
// Do work
unsafe {
    rwlock.unlock_exclusive();
}

// Read access
rwlock.lock_shared();
// Do work
unsafe {
    rwlock.unlock_shared();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You always can do this:

```rust
let lock = RwLock::new(0);
let mut guard = lock.write().unwrap();
*guard += 1;
drop(guard);
// lock is unlocked now.

let guard = lock.read().unwrap();
println!("{}", *guard);
drop(guard);
// lock is unlocked now.
```

Comment: Why use a dummy integer? Use a `RwLock<()>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You cannot show data modification example with `()` unfortunately. And OP doesn't want to store data in another place than lock.

Comment: This is the ordinary `RwLock` usage, where I have to store `guard` for as long as the lock is held.